# Space between views in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

I have a linear layout inside a scroll view, this linear layout contains many table layouts that are inserted dynamically during the application life. When I have more than 1 table layout they are too close to one another:

[image]

Here is the code for the table layouts:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/eggshell" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageBoardTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fill"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageBoardMessageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fill" />

</TableRow>
```

and this is the code of the scroll view and the linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/messgaeBoardScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/messageBoardLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How can I create some kind of a break between the two table layouts?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you go for the `android:layout_margin` parameter in android... It will allow you to put some space between any two layout or between layout and screen border..

Check out this [Android Developer Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)..

Hope it will help you..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_margin` instead of `padding`

Padding adds space inside the layout, not between other layout

Answer (score 0):

Remove your padding from your `TableLayout`  which is `android:padding="10dp"` besides that try out with the margin `android:margin="10dp"`.

As padding adds space in outer part of the view and margin leaves a space in inner part of your view.

Comment: I tried to add android:margin but it gave me an error saying no resource identifier found for attribute margin in package android

Comment: @DorMesica Try to clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:margin_top=10dp;
```

instead of layout_padding.